Order items, product with options set sku with custom delimeter
I have a simple product with options.
When I add to the cart and buy, I have a new SKU with the delimiter '-'. I would like to change the delimiter, where can I do that?
Example simple product SKU: AAA
and has custom options Sku
Option 1
A1A1A1
A2A2A2
Option 2
B1B1B1
B2B2B2
On the Product page, SKU is showing AAA is fine.
Now if the customer Added to the cart and chooses the first option in both sections for this product its SKU Becomes AAA-A1A1A1-B1B1B1 in the cart and the Order
I want to change it's separator from - to +
so the result SKU becomes AAA+A1A1A1+B1B1B1

The Sku delimiter is defined in method getOptionSku of the class Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType .
Just change the value of $skuDelimiter
Editing Vendor files is not advised, since the getOptionSku is public you can use a plugin:
https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/plugins/

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Simple" type="Vendor\OrderSync\Model\Rewrite\Product\Type\Simple" />
</config>


Work!If you have Virtual Products don't forget to do the same.
